# Phonegap Accelerometer Demo App stops running

Tags: android, cordova, accelerometer

I have tried numerous times to the the accelerometer demo from PhoneGaps site,

(http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer)

,to work and it works fine but with shake or a slight change in orientation the app shuts down and then returns to the previous activity on the device, either the home screen or what ever I was doing when installing the app from eclipse.  This is on the android build of PhoneGap.

I am wondering if anyone else is having this issue and what had been done to get around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

probably has something to do with your shaking moving the app from landscape to portrait or vice-versa. I had a similar problem and just set added android:screenOrientation="portrait"   to my activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file for my project. Didn't have time to REALLY debug it.....